# JVM choices on Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, jvm

What are the JVM implementations available on Windows Mobile?

[Esmertec JBed](http://www.esmertec.com/40.html) is the one on my WinMo phone.

Wondering how many other JVM vendors are in this zone. Are there any comparison or benchmarking data available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JVM Choices for Windows CE in general (including Pocket PC and Windows Mobile):

- CrE-ME
- [Mysaifu](http://www2s.biglobe.ne.jp/~dat/java/project/jvm/index_en.html)
- [Skelmir CEEJ](http://www.skelmir.com/solutions/handheld.html)

If you're looking to have a common code base between WinMo and Symbina, you might also look at [Red Five Labs](http://www.redfivelabs.com/). They have a Symbian runtime that allows you to run COmpact Framework apps, so you could have a CF codebase that works on both.  I evaluated the early betas of Red Five's offering, but haven't used it since, so I can't attest to the quality or coverage.

Answer (score 1):

The reason was to have same codebase in WinMo and Symbian.

My personal preference would be to have native solution on both. But that would mean, developing & maintaining two set of code bases. And the management does not prefer that for some reason ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 JVMs for WinMo, Mysaifu for J2SE and IBM WebSphere Everyplace Micro Environment for J2ME.

Answer (score 1):

Prakash, since your goal is to have a common code base between J2ME and WinMo handsets, check out alcheMo. alcheMo is not a JVM, but a fully automated J2ME to native Win32 WinMo porting solution.

Answer (score 1):

Even when running a little late on this question and just for completenes sake: [JBlend(micro)](http://www.aplixcorp.com/en/products/jb_micro/overview.html) is the Java environment for Windows Mobile 6.1 and 6.5 which is used e.g. on HTC devices. It enables for CLDC and MIDP 1.0 and 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

[phoneME](http://davy.preuveneers.be/phoneme/) ([java.net page](http://java.net/projects/phoneme)) seems to be a another choice. It is recommended by the [LWUIT FAQ](http://download.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/lwuit-1.4/LWUIT_Developer_Guide_HTML/bbjgjggh.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but wouldn't it make more sense to target your software at the .NET framework compact edition if you're developing for WinMo?

Answer (score 0):

HP also had a JVM called HP Chai on their old models of Pocket PC