# Windows Mobile 6 J2SE-scale JVM implementation

Tags: windows-mobile, java-me, java

Does anybody have experience of a decent J2SE (preferably at least Java JDK 1.5-level) Java Virtual Machine for Windows Mobile 6? If you know of any CLDC VMs, I'm also interested because even that would be better than what we [currently have](http://www.nsicom.com/Default.aspx?tabid=138) for the platform.

Comment: There's [another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322/jvm-choices-on-windows-mobile) now about the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I've tried doing things with Java on Windows Mobile. I tried really hard. The best advise I can give you is: Stop right now, and start using .NET Compact Framework.

Anyway, the two 'good' JVMs for WM are [IBM-J9](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/wireless/weme/) and NSICom Creme, which still are both terribile to work with. You've already seen Creme - IBM-J9 isn't much better. They are slow, clumsy, not native looking and hard to install for end users. Also don't ever think of doing exotic things like dialing a phonenumber or even launching another application. If you really want to try, there's an evaluation version of J9 available [here](http://www-128.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/zones/wireless/weme_eval_runtimes.html?S_CMP=rnav). (which is identical to the full version).

I'm not against Java in any way, but on Windows Mobile i recommend saving the trouble and using C#.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I searched a while and there no decent JVM for windows mobile. The best bet I think is this : http://www2s.biglobe.ne.jp/~dat/java/project/jvm/index_en.html but it's JDK 1.3 compliant the last time I checked.

Comment: Thanks. I could try that because even 1.3 is a lot better than 1.1 which I'm stuck with currently. There is also IBM J9/Webshere Everyplace Micro Environment which might help. Why on earth IBM has named a small embeddable JVM after it's ultra-heavy mammoth product is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

You might also look at [Skelmir's CEEJ](http://www.skelmir.com/solutions/handheld.html).  It's been several years since I used it, but even then I was impressed with their code coverage and especially the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following like, this is a J2SE compatiable JVM for WM5/WM6:

http://www2s.biglobe.ne.jp/~dat/java/project/jvm/index_en.html

Answer (score 0):

Try CEEJ VM. It’s very low footprint Java vm with optimisation for embedded systems. Fast and native compiler and interpreter.