# Is it possible to run java programs on Windows CE?

Tags: windows-mobile

Is it possible to run java programs on Windows CE ?

thank's

Comment: possible duplicate of [JVM choices on Windows Mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322/jvm-choices-on-windows-mobile)

Answer (score 5):

Asked and answered:

- [java (ME) on windows mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517906/java-me-on-windows-mobile)
- [Can I run java programs in a Windows Mobile 6 device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699841/can-i-run-java-programs-in-a-windows-mobile-6-device)
- [Windows Mobile 6 J2SE-scale JVM implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76214/windows-mobile-6-j2se-scale-jvm-implementation)
- [JVM choices on Windows Mobile..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322/jvm-choices-on-windows-mobile)

Comment: conclusion: there is no Java on WinCE/WinMobile. Use .NET Compact Framework, Luke!

Answer (score 2):

There is [CrEme](http://www.cremejvm.com/) VM, which is very stable, but you need to pay for it.

There is also IBM's J9 JVM, but I can't find a link for it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can run J2ME usign this:

http://www.windowsfordevices.com/news/NS2454472990.html

Don't know about full grown Java. I doubt it though.