# Can I run Java Program in Windows CE Operating System?

Tags: java, windows-ce

Before I actually give you details of my question, let me set a context where I'm in.
I've been working on this Java for server years to build both Web and Android applications in Windows OS. 
But recently, I've got a requirement to execute a Java Program in Windows CE Operating System. And this seemed very different to me.
I neither find any documentation regarding installation nor much community help. So here's are my questions

0) Is it possible to run a plain console java Hello world program with Windows CE?
1) Can we Install JRE in Windows CE? if yes, how?
2) Can we Run a Java Program?
3) Is there any alternative way?

I've seen similar queries like mine i.e
[Is it possible to run java programs on Windows CE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882732/is-it-possible-to-run-java-programs-on-windows-ce) But couldn't find much help.

Note: This link more related to Windows Mobile which is subset of Windows CE. And also has accepted answer. So It didn't help me much in order to understand my question.

Comment: What about the answers to the linked question is unclear? It looks like the only option is still the commercial product from MicroDoc, and even that only supports WinCE 7 (2009).

Comment: @user2864740 I've already linked the same question to mention that didn't help me. If so, how could you make it duplicate again??? The link doesn't have an accepted answer as well.

Comment: See the first comment. Duplicating a question on purpose isn't a very good way to solicit "alternative" answers. A bounty can be offered for existing questions.

Comment: @JimGarrison Those answers were more related to Windows Mobile which is subset of Windows CE. But I've a device with Windows CE and I wanted to run java in it.

Answer (score 2):

"Windows Embedded Compact" is not such a operating system that meets the minimum system requirements for running jdk and jre.

So you will need a system that meets the minimum system requirements. For this you can check "Oracle" website.