# Java (ME) on Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, java-me

Does anyone have experience deploying Java ME apps to Windows Mobile? What are the high-level steps to getting started with this, and are there any major drawbacks?

Comment: Pretty much a dupe of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322/jvm-choices-on-windows-mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well at first you need to install a JVM on your device (if one isn't already installed). There are currently two players for this:

- [NSI Creme](http://www.nsicom.com/Default.aspx?tabid=138). This is a robust product but it only supports CDC profile (no MIDlets) and you need to buy a license for at least 1000 devices or so.
- IBM J9. This has CLCD support and can run MIDlets. There is a demo version, but I wasn't able to find a download link. May be IBM has stopped supporting it.

Some devices have a JVM pre-installed, but it is difficult to rely on certain profiles being present. Unless you are targeting a single device, I would say that is better to avoid J2ME for Windows Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Just beginning with the Samsung i900. FileConnection seems all bad with no obvious access to the internal hard drive or the memory card. Worried about the Applix jBlend base port.

I *hope* others have a better experience of java on windows mobile.

Answer (score 0):

kgiannakakis is right with the JavaVM that needs to be installed on Windows Mobile devices, but this only counts for older devices. Windows Mobile 5 and 6 come with a pre-installed Microsoft Java VM which works. Basically.

You can actually just compile your J2ME application to a jar file, copy it on your Windows Mobile device and start it. That's pretty much it.

As with all generic JavaME VM's you will not be able to access internal API's / hardware which is not accessible from within the standard CLDC/MIDP libraries the JavaVM you are using, supports.