# Does windows phone 6.5 support perst lite?

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

does windows mobile OS 6.5 support Perst lite DB for persistent storage??
or which version of perst does windows mobile os support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well according to [the product's own web page](http://www.mcobject.com/j2me_database) (which is probably a reliable source of information):

> Perst Lite is McObject’s version of the Perst open source, object-oriented embedded database for mobile and embedded applications on the Java ME platform.

We can reasonably infer from this that the target platform has to run Java ME.

So the question, really then, is "does WinMo support Java?"  That question has been answered here on SO [more than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322/jvm-choices-on-windows-mobile) [once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517906/java-me-on-windows-mobile).

Comment: The thing is Perst for windows phone OS was only introduced in windows phone 7. now how do i know whether previous OS(windows 6.5) was supporting perst or perst lite????

Comment: Ask the product developers (McObject) maybe?  And Perst's docs (not Perst Lite) explicitly say it supports the CF.  Pull the code - they provide it - and build it to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Right - the product you want is not Perst Lite (which runs on Java ME). You want the .NET version of Perst. I believe with Perst for .NET's support for .NET Compact Framework, using it with Windows Phone 6.5 should not be a problem.

Perst for .NET, with complete source code, is available for free download here - http://www.mcobject.com/perst_eval