# Can I run java programs in a Windows Mobile 6 device?

Tags: java, tcp

I need to run a java program in a Windows Mobile 6 device. Is this possible? I need to do some tcp/ip programming with that so I can communicate to other computers. It's a simple computer class project, nothing fancy. Just sending messages and small files. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JVM choices on Windows Mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322/jvm-choices-on-windows-mobile)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can run J2ME apps on Windows Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this posible JVM's on windows mobile.
[http://www2s.biglobe.ne.jp/~dat/java/project/jvm/index_en.html](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamesdk/entry/jvm_for_windows_mobile)
or
https://blogs.oracle.com/javamesdk/entry/jvm_for_windows_mobile