# Deploy Blackberry application on Windows Mobile!

Tags: windows-mobile, blackberry

We are having an application developed for BlackBerry - a pretty big one only. Is it possible to deploy the same as Windows CE/Windows Mobile 6 application? We want to reuse the application with minimal changes.

Lemme admit that I've little/zero knowledge of the Mobile applications.

EDIT: The application is developed in J2ME.

Comment: What is the program developed in? J2ME/Brew/c...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delveloped your app as a midlet you can run in JVM for WinMo, but if you developed your app for blackberry (you used a blackberry specified thing like GUI ) then the answer is no. you must to write a midlet or the best way to implement the whole project in C#, C++ or maybe the less changes need if you rewrite your code to MIDP.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's J2ME the odds are at least better than 0%, though probably not much.  You'll need to find [a JVM for WinMo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322/jvm-choices-on-windows-mobile) (it doesn't ship with one) and then test to see if your app will load and run under that JVM.  Good luck, but don't hold your breath.

Comment: @ctacke : Thanks for the inputs and wishes. :) Is it possible to extract the java files from the BlackBerry's COD file?

Comment: No clue  I'd start anotehr question asking exactly that.